# How can the colour of the Material Design icons be changed to suit a specific theme?

Tags: android, android-theme

I have downloaded the Material Design icons from here [Material Design Icons](https://www.google.com/design/icons/). The icons are all in black. In my application, I would like to use the same icons in white.

What would be the way for changing the icon colours?

I am not able to use photo editing tools for changing the icon colour.

Update: I tried with android:tint but it did not work:

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
    android:tint="#FFFFFFFF"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

Comment: All answers in a nutshell: http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icons-for-android

Answer (score 2):

You can also download them in white from the material design website.
[image: Material design web color selection]

For tinting drawables you can use [DrawableCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html).

Example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788251/android-tint-using-drawablecompat):

```
Drawable normalDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_to_tint);
Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(normalDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable,getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set in XML in the ImageView tag

```
anroid:tint="@color/your_color"
```

or in Java

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
```

You can read more about it [on ImageView API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter))

Comment: I tried with android:tint, but it didn't make any difference. Please see the update in the main description

Answer (score 0):

You can download Google's Material Design icons from [GitHub](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons), where they come in black, grey and white. Or, there are a couple of plugins you can use for `Android Studio` that give you the option to apply a colour scheme: [here is one of them](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin)