# DrawableCompat setTint not working on API 19

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-drawable

I am using the DrawableCompat for tinting drawable as below, tinting doesn't seem to be working on API 19. I am using the support lib version 23.3.0

```
Drawable drawable = textView.getCompoundDrawables()[drawablePosition];
if (drawable != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            drawable.setTint(color);
        } else {
            DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable), color);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem. I combined the posts in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30928051 and tried the APIs 17, 19, 21, 22, 23 and N Preview 3 with SupportLib 23.4.0 to find a solution.

Even if it is mentioned, that the compat-class will use a filter for pre-lollipop-devices (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27812472/2170109), it's not working.

Now, I check the API myself and use the following code, which is working on all tested APIs (for 17 and up).

```
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/30928051/2170109
    Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.vector));
    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    /*
     * need to use the filter | https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880522/2170109
     * (even if compat should use it for pre-API21-devices | https://stackoverflow.com/a/27812472/2170109)
     */
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourcolor);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color);

    } else {
        drawable.mutate().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
```

Comment: Finally something that worked for me on lollipop. Thank you very much for sharing.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Lollipop (API 21).
I had to change the minimum version to API 22 (Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1).

Comment: Combining the answers from hardysim and @Eselfar worked in my case.

Answer (score 19):

Works on **API 15-25** using AppCompat Support Library (tested on 24.1.1 and above).

```
public static Drawable getTintedDrawable(@NonNull final Context context,
                                         @DrawableRes int drawableRes, @ColorRes int colorRes) {
    Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableRes);
    d = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(d.mutate(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes));
    return d;
}
```

Comment: I tried with the Support Library 24.2.1 and it doesn't work on API 19 unfortunately. I moved on @hardysim's solution.

Comment: Works for me on API 19/21/25 with support library 25.1.1

Comment: Only `mutate()` was enough in my case.

Comment: @Eselfar this works, however note that you have to add the line 
 d = DrawableCompat. wrap(d); This wraps the drawable for mutating it while setting tint

Comment: It works with only `DrawableCompat.wrap(Drawable)` being added. May I ask what is the of use of `.mutate()` in the above case?

Answer (score 2):

I think that after wrapping your drawable, you would need to call `mutate()` on it. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30928051/3032209

Answer (score 2):

based on [@localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39095848/3208541) answer

```
Drawable d = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_rate));
DrawableCompat.setTint(d, Color.parseColor("#AAAAAA"));
l.setLogo(d);
```

I tried on API 19>25 and it works well

Answer (score 0):

I made following helper method to set a drawable with tint and it works at least from API level 16 up to x. The color is a themed color and therefore resolved via attribute.

```
  public static Drawable getTintedDrawable(int drawableResourceId, int colorAttribute) {
    YourApplication = YourApplication.getInstance();
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(application, drawableResourceId);
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    int tintColor = ContextCompat.getColor(application, application.getThemedResourceId(colorAttribute));
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, tintColor);
    return drawable;
  }
```

Without the drawable.wrap it works on higher versions but not on api level 16.

Answer (score 0):

```html
val textInput = EditText(context)

val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_drawable)
        drawable?.let { myDrawable ->
            DrawableCompat.setTint(myDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color))
            textInput.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, myDrawable, null)
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Could you pls add a bit of an explanation with your answer?

Answer (score -1):

No answer works for me on Honor 4X. so I searched more and found this:

Just you need to ask your drawable to update itself by `.invalidateSelf()`

```
private void setTint(Drawable drawable, int color) {
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        drawable.invalidateSelf();
}
```

[Resourse: **Tips for DrawableCompat.setTint() Under API 21**](https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/tips-for-drawablecompat-settint-under-api-21-1e62a32fc033#b192)

Comment: I think that condition is not necessary too!