# DrawableCompat.setTint not reliable?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, drawable

I have two `ImageView` (up, down) which I want to update in color depending on certain actions. There are three different cases:

`up red, down black`

`up black, down red`

`up green, down green`

I have three functions for changing the colors accordingly that get executed in the correct place (I have a TextView that prints out what is currently called, and the result is as expected), but I found that often they don't work correctly - as in that they only color one ImageView. As I wrote above, those are the three possible cases - however sometimes one imageview is green and the other red, or both imageviews are red, or only one imageview is green despite being in the `up green, down green` case - which shouldn't happen. Here are the functions:

```
/** 17170452 = green
 * 17170444 = black
 * 17170455 = red
 */
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun colorTuned() {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(down.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, 17170452))
        DrawableCompat.setTint(up.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, 17170452))
    }
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun colorDown() {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(down.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, 17170455))
        DrawableCompat.setTint(up.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, 17170444))
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun colorUp() {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(down.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, 17170444))
        DrawableCompat.setTint(up.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, 17170455))
    }
```

How can those wrong cases happen here?

Comment: Are you calling `DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)` somewhere? or `mutate()` your drawable?

Comment: No, the code I posted is the only code that's got something to do with changing the color

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/q/36731919/2940733 out

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it to work thanks to the answer by hardysim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val drawableUp = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_play_arrow)!!)
up.setImageDrawable(drawableUp)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawableUp, ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorTop))

} else {
    drawableUp.mutate().colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(colorTop, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)
}
```

This did it in my case